# adding javascript code to any website and execute the function added on every click on document in webdriver

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, webdriver

What i have done is here written a code in webdriver which will add following javascript code to any website i open

> Javascript code

```
<script>
var hilightElement = function(e) {
var event = e || window.event;
var target = e.target || e.srcElement;  
e.srcElement.style.border = "solid blue 1px";      
};  
if (document.addEventListener){  
document.addEventListener('click', hilightElement, false); 
} 
else if (document.attachEvent){     
document.attachEvent('onclick', hilightElement); 
}
</script>
```

> Webdriver Code

```
public static void injectJavaScript(WebDriver oDriver,String sJavaScript)
{
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) oDriver;
    String s=oDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/head")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
    s=s.replaceFirst("</title>", "</title>\n"+sJavaScript);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) oDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML='" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(s) + "'", oDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/head")));
}
```

But it is not working i searched and they say it has something to do with reloading the script

What am i missing here?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to re-inject that script every time a new page loads. Writing a browser extension would be a better solution than WebDriver for this problem, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to append to head and all just execute it.and remove the script  tag from the string

```
public static void injectJavaScript(WebDriver oDriver,String sJavaScript)
{
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) oDriver;
    js.executeScript(sJavaScript);
}
```

Comment: with the <script> </script> tags ?

Comment: without the script tags.I mean remove them